# what is irq/464-14c2000 android

Tags: kernel, processes, developer-options

What's this process doing in android?

irq/464-14c2000

I see it often - when cpu usage is turned on in developer options of my android device.

Is it some kind of interrupt service routine?

it has a PPID of 2

Answer (score 0):

The only place I've seen mentions of something like this: [XDA-Developers](http://The%20only%20place%20I've%20seen%20mentions%20of%20something%20like%20this:%20[link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-galaxy-s6-edge/general/rom-development-notes-t3069208).%20From%20the%20other%20items%20it%20looks%20like%20it's%20the%20interrupt%20request%20(IRQ)%20from%20various%20hardware%20(flip%20cover,%20sensor,%20NFC,%20etc.))

From the names of other items, it looks like it's indeed the interrupt request (IRQ) from various hardware (you can see flip cover, sensor, NFC, power management IC (pmic), etc.), but there are ones with similar cryptic numbers whose purpose is unknown to me.

My advice? Just ignore it.